# Визуализация структуры классов в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Существует ли расширение для Visual Studio, которое бы графически показывала структуру классов, все наследования и тому подобное?

Comment: Вроде было в стандартной поставке (если у вас не community edition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо в установочнике Visual Studio Installer добавить пакет "Class Designer" (если не ошибаюсь, то так). Затем в проекте, в Solution Explorer нужно выделить все необходимые для отображения классы/структуры, нажать правой кнопкой > View Class Diagram